# What is the difference between a power slide and a hockey stop?

Tags: terminology, skating

What is the difference between a hockey stop and a power slide.  After watching demonstrations of both I can't see a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hockey stop is basically letting the blade of your skate slide across the ice. It doesn't require much force or direction, just the movement of your upper body and leg to angle the skate slightly. A power slide is used to make a quick or sharp turn. You slide your lead skate around and drag your other across the ice, sliding it. Obviously one is a stop, while the other is a turn basically. They are extremely close in look. I was confused myself when I first saw your question.

Comment: A year and some later, I understand the difference and can do both (at least in one direction). :)